# Next.js DOMPurify.sanitize() shows TypeError: dompurify__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default.a.sanitize is not a function

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering, dompurify

I am using `DOMPurify.sanitize()` inside `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{}}` to display `innerHtml` returned from the database. For initial purpose I'm using `getServersideProps()` with `next-redux-wrapper` for this page.

I installed dompurify with: `npm i -S dompurify`, present version is: "^2.2.6".

My code:

```
    import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
    import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
    import { END } from 'redux-saga';
    import wrapper from '../redux/storeSetup';

    const EmployeePage = () => {
    
        const blog = useSelector(state => state.data);

        const html_body = blog[0].body_html;
    
        const clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(html_body);
    
        return(
           <div className="mainContainer">
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML ={{ __html: clean }} />
                <ul>
                    {blog.map((item) => (
                        <li key={item.author}>
                            <span>{item.author}</span><br/>
                            <span>{item.title}</span>
                            <h4>{item.body_delta}</h4>
                            <p>{item.body_html}</p>
                            <p>{item.created_on}</p>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

    export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps( async ({store}) => {
        store.dispatch({type: GET_DATA});
        store.dispatch(END);
        await store.sagaTask.toPromise();    
    });
    export default EmployeePage;
```

But when I'm running this with `npm run dev` I'm getting this error:
`TypeError: dompurify__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.sanitize is not a function`.

What is wrong here? I tried with even simpler codes but everything shows the same error! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 46):

Use [Isomorphic dompurify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-dompurify)

It can render on server side and browser

Comment: https://github.com/kkomelin/isomorphic-dompurify/issues/54

Comment: this is the simplest way, I think it should be marked as solver

Comment: I still get the same error with this

Answer (score 8):

I just switch to [js-xss](https://github.com/leizongmin/js-xss) and made a component like that :

```
import React from "react";
import xss from "xss";

const Html = ({ unsafeHtml }: {unsafeHtml: string}): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div
      {...props}
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: xss(unsafeHtml),
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: A `bower.json` file in a library with type definitions. Never thought I'd see the day.

Answer (score 1):

I found a working solution: instead of sanitizing the innerHtml on the server side, I had to sanitize it on the client side right after submitting the rich-text blog, in my case, `react-quill`:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import {useState} from 'react'
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

const QuillNoSSRWrapper = dynamic(import('react-quill'), {
    ssr: false,
    loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
})

// quill modules definitions
//...

export default function articles() {
    const [text, setText] = useState(preData);

    function handleTextChange(content, delta, source, editor) {
        //let str = JSON.stringify(editor.getContents());
        //let parsed = JSON.parse(str)
        setText(editor.getContents());
        const cleaned = DOMPurify.sanitize(editor.getHTML());
        console.log('Cleaned Html: ', cleaned);

    return (
        <div className="quill_container">
            <div id="editor" className="editor">
                <QuillNoSSRWrapper
                    id="quilleditor"
                    modules={modules}
                    formats={formats}
                    theme="snow"
                    value={text}
                    onChange={handleTextChange}
                  />
             </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this yesterday with a TypeScript/React set up.

```
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

export const sanitize = (html: string): string => DOMPurify.sanitize(html);
```

This code worked perfectly inside Jest tests but failed in the Browser as the DOMPurify object was undefined.
Upon digging I found that there was a DOMPurify object attached at the window scope. I wound up having to put a hack inplace to handle the differing behavior between running in node and in the browser:

```
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

interface IDOMPurifyWindow extends Window {
    DOMPurify: typeof DOMPurify;
}
const purify =
    ((window as unknown) as IDOMPurifyWindow)?.DOMPurify || DOMPurify;

export const sanitize = (html: string): string => DOMPurify.sanitize(html);
```

There is a compiler warning but it's functional.
I could eliminate the compiler warning by importing the es.js version of the library directly: `import DOMPurify from 'dompurify/dist/purify.es.js';` But that resulted in Jest being unable to run as it needs vanilla JavaScript.

This library does great things, but it's not super friendly to use if you're using TypeScript and running in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from the two other solutions of this thread - [isomorphic-dompurify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66799141/5404186) and the one provided on [Github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65646062/5404186).

---

1. In a `jest-setup.ts` file (provided in the `jest.config` as
   `setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest-setup.ts"]`):

```
const DOMPurify = require("dompurify");
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const { window } = new JSDOM("<!DOCTYPE html>");
global.DOMPurify = DOMPurify(window);
```

This will make DOMPurify work with Jest.

2. In your app code, handles DOMPurify for both `window` and `global` sides so that it works both in the browser and in jest / NodeJS contexts. e.g. in TypeScript

```
import { sanitize as DOMPurifySanitize } from "dompurify";

export const sanitize = (text: string): string => {
  const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
  return isBrowser ? DOMPurifySanitize(text) : global.DOMPurify.sanitize(text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea! Should jest-setup.ts be jest-setup.js?

Comment: Depends your setup. We are using TypeScript for our jest configuration as well, therefore `jest-setup.ts` but, if you don't, sure `jest-setup.js` works too.

Answer (score 1):

Using DOMPurify in Next.js can be accomplished with by installing [`jsdom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) and [`canvas`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) to construct a `window` object and pass to the `DOMPurify()` function.

CodeSandbox Demo (uses app directory): https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/lingering-river-j5fpi7?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx

### Instructions

First, install the libraries:

```bash
npm install jsdom canvas
```

#### App Router version (Server Component)

In the `app/` directory, you can use React Server Components to run `jsdom` on the server:

```
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: DOMPurify(new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html>').window).sanitize(
          '<img src=x onerror=alert(1)//>'
        ),
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

#### Pages Router version

```
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

export default function Home(props) {
  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: props.sanitizedHtml,
      }}
    />
  );
}

export function getServerSideProps() {
  const sanitizedHtml =
    DOMPurify(new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html>').window).sanitize(
      '<img src=x onerror=alert(1)//>'
    );
  return {
    props: {
      sanitizedHtml: sanitizedHtml,
    },
  };
}
```

In the `pages/` directory, you'll also need to configure webpack to mark `jsdom` and `canvas` as externals (add the `webpack` key to your `next.config.js` file):

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.externals = [...config.externals, 'canvas', 'jsdom'];
    return config;
  },
};
```

More details here:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46893

Comment: The bundle size of Jsdom seems crazy.

Comment: Bundle size is not as much of a concern with React Server Components and the (older) `getServerSideProps` that are used in my examples above - jsdom is running on the server, not included in the client bundle (and not sent to the client)

Answer (score 0):

`dompurify` just work on client side component, so you need to add this line `"use client";` to top of (tsx,jsx) file, see this full example :

```
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

export default function MarkdownTextView({text}: { text: string }) {
    const [sanitizedHtml, setSanitizedHtml] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        // This code will be executed only on the client side after the component is mounted
        if (text.length === 0) return;

        const domPurify = DOMPurify(window);
        const cleanHtml = domPurify.sanitize(text); // You might want to pass your markdown-converted HTML here
        setSanitizedHtml(cleanHtml);
    }, [text]); // This effect will re-run if the 'text' prop changes

    if (!sanitizedHtml) return null; // or some placeholder/loading indicator

    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: sanitizedHtml}}></div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to this:
https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify/issues/29#issuecomment-466626162

Try the follow (from the example above):

```
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom'
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify'
const { window } = new JSDOM(html_body);
const domPurify = DOMPurify(window);
console.log(domPurify.sanitize(html_body));
```

Comment: Installed jsdom and ran, it's showing this: `Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'`!

Comment: Is the jsdom approach available for production?

Comment: This solution is for sanitization on the server-side only. If you try to run this in the browser as well it will give you an error.